# Odoo 8 - on_record_write() not triggered for 'state' field on stock.picking

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, connector

So I am using the connector to send a status to Magento depending on the status of a stock.picking record in Odoo.

Here is the (beginning of the) function that I use for that :

```
 @on_record_write(model_names = 'stock.picking')
def change_status_sale_order_sp(session, model_name,
                             record_id, vals):
    if session.context.get('connector_no_export'):
        return
    record = session.env['stock.picking'].browse(record_id)


    if "IN" in record.name: #the stock pickings might be to receive products from the supplier, but we want the one for the deliveries to customers
        return
    origin = record.origin        #String containing the sale order ID + the warehouse from where the order is shipped
    so_name = origin.split(':')[0]
    warehouse = origin.split(':')[1]
    status = record.state

    _logger.debug("STOCK PICKING --- Delivery order " + str(record_id) + " was modified : " + str(vals))
```

I want that function to be called when there is a change on a stock.picking record, hence the decorator on_record_write.

My problem is : that function is called for every write action (every time a field is modified, either manually or on the server side) on a stock.picking record, EXCEPT when it is the state field. I never get the 'vals' parameter to be {'state': whateverthestatusis}. Why is that, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

on_record_write() will every time call when write method of stock.picking will call.

But state field is fields.function field and it will set based on stock moves so you will not get state field in vals of write.